# Как привести в нормальный вид 1.0E-5

Tags: php

Пытаюсь убрать лишние нули

```
floatval(000.0000100) = 1.0E-5
000.0000100+0 = 1.0E-5
+000.0000100 = 1.0E-5
```

Числа могут быть разные. `number_format` требует точного количества числе после запятой.

Comment: @shogun, что подразумевается под нормальным видом?

Comment: так 0.00001

Comment: http://ideone.com/UMoQyZ  
[PHP:sprintf](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php)

Comment: @ReinRaus ничего не выйдет честными методами http://ideone.com/nsTRRH

Comment: @shogun, в силу природы дробных чисел многие числа типа 0.03 на самом деле являются числами 0.030000....000АБВ (если ничего не путаю, то со степенью десятки в этом плане все нормально). Поэтому определение знака, за которым надо обрезать - не очень тривиальная задача, проще всего через остаток от деления и максимальный допустимый знак, наверное. Что критичного в паре лишних нулей?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Снизошло на меня озарение, придумал я велосипед

```
$number = number_format(1.0E-5, 20);
$number = rtrim($number, '0');
var_dump($number); // string(7) "0.00001"
```

Потому что изначально надо было подходить к этому *PHP-way*

Comment: я поломал ваш велосипед http://ideone.com/yJ6lEn есть подозрение что эта задача решается только парсингом E нотации :)

Comment: решил так
http://ideone.com/zubO7d

Answer (score 0):

```
$num = "000.0000100";
$fl = floatval ($num);

printf ("%.05f", $fl);
// Result: 0.00001
```

Comment: @shogun Собственно сабж